# Surface Integrals, orientation and parametrizations.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Integrate $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ over the surface $z=12$ $x^2 + y^2 \leq 25$

I parametrized the surface with $\sigma (r, \theta) = r \sin(\theta), r \cos(\theta), 12)$ with $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt(25) $ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Then since $\sigma _{r} \times \sigma_{\theta} = (0,0,-r)$ I get that

$\int_S f ds =  \int _{0} ^{\sqrt(25)} \int _0 ^{2\pi} (r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta,12).(0,0,-r) d\theta dr = \int _{0} ^{\sqrt(25)} \int _0 ^{2\pi} (-12 r) d\theta dr = -300\pi $

Problem is that my book lists the answer as $300\pi$.

My thinking is that the unitary outwards pointing normal of the surface is $(0,0,1)$ so my parametrization doesn't preserve the orientation, then I should multiply by -1 when solving the integral.

But

My question is, is there a way to do this without going through the outwards normal vector? I went back to the definition of surface integrals and it makes no mention of orientation really.

Comment: Huh, you're right, thanks. I'm not sure I get why it's wrong though, should I always use up for some reason?

Comment: It depends on the orientation of the surface; if you don't have it, you can only have a result "up to the sign". If you want to obtain $300\pi$, just consider $\theta$ to be the "first" and $r$ the "second" parameter (for example).

Comment: Yeah, that was my impression too but since the book didn't say anything about it I thought maybe I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the confirmation.